# remove element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

NewBie for d3.js.  I try to remove xAxis, based on the method

> s.selectAll("g").remove(xAxis);

but it does not work.  Not sure if it is the correct way to remove xAxis? Thank you in advance.

```
1. var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);


2. s.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)

3. s.selectAll("g").remove(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.remove()` doesn't take any arguments, it is just a method you can use on any d3 selection.

To remove features you have to first select them, and then remove them:

```
d3.selectAll('g').remove(); // removes all 'g' elements from the DOM.
d3.selectAll('.point').remove(); // removes all elements with the class 'point'
```

To illustrate, the following code draws a circle:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',40)
  .attr('cy',40)
  .attr('r',10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You can remove the circle multiple ways. You could use `circle.remove();` as the variable `circle` is a selection that includes that circle.

Or you could select circles that are in the svg: `svg.selectAll('circle').remove();`

Or you could just select all `circle`s in the DOM with `d3.selectAll('circle').remove();`

Method 1:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',40)
  .attr('cy',40)
  .attr('r',10);
  
circle.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Method 2:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',40)
  .attr('cy',40)
  .attr('r',10);
  
svg.selectAll('circle').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Method 3:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var circle = svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx',40)
  .attr('cy',40)
  .attr('r',10);
  
d3.selectAll('circle').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In your case you could try variations of the above approaches:

```
var axis = s.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

axis.remove();
```

Or you could give it a class or id and use that to remove it:

```
s.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr('id', 'xAxis')
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

d3.selectAll('#xAxis').remove();
```