# d3js remove last tspan node

Tags: d3.js, css-selectors, tspan

I have something similar to this

```
var textBox = somecontainer.append('text')
...
textBox.append('tspan').text('First ')
textBox.append('tspan').text('Second ')
textBox.append('tspan').text('Third ')
...
textBox.append('tspan').text('nth ')
```

Later on I need to remove programatically the last child tspan node from the textBox stack.
How ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove element in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079951/remove-element-in-d3-js)

Comment: `textbox.select("tspan:last-child").remove()`